# Adding a row number respecting the order of each row

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table like this

```
id, period, tag
1     1      A
1     2      A
1     3      B
1     4      A
1     5      A
1     6      A
2     1      A
2     2      B
2     3      B
2     4      B
2     5      B
2     6      A
```

I would like to add a new column with a ranking, respecting the order of the row given my column 'period' to obtain something like this

```
id, period, tag  rank
1     1      A     1
1     2      A     1
1     3      B     2
1     4      A     3
1     5      A     3
1     6      A     3
2     1      A     1
2     2      B     2
2     3      B     2
2     4      B     2
2     5      B     2
2     6      A     3
```

What can I do?

I try rank and dense_rank function without any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another candidate for CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT() 
less code, and quite effective, too ...!

```
WITH
input(id,period,tag) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,4,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,5,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,6,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,3,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,5,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,6,'A'
)
SELECT
  *
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(tag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY period) + 1 AS rank
FROM input;
-- out  id | period | tag | rank 
-- out ----+--------+-----+------
-- out   1 |      1 | A   |    1
-- out   1 |      2 | A   |    1
-- out   1 |      3 | B   |    2
-- out   1 |      4 | A   |    3
-- out   1 |      5 | A   |    3
-- out   1 |      6 | A   |    3
-- out   2 |      1 | A   |    1
-- out   2 |      2 | B   |    2
-- out   2 |      3 | B   |    2
-- out   2 |      4 | B   |    2
-- out   2 |      5 | B   |    2
-- out   2 |      6 | A   |    3
-- out (12 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (12 rows): 14.823 ms. All rows formatted: 14.874 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a cumulative sum based on a `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_tag = tag then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by period) as rank
from (select t.*, lag(tag) over (partition by id order by period) as prev_tag
      from t
     ) t;
```